# feed multiple csr_matrix to feed_dict in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have 50 csr_matrix, all of which have the same shape [1000, 1000]. How do I feed them to feed_dict for using placeholder in tensorflow.

Thanks.

Comment: You need [`tf.sparse.placeholder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/placeholder).

Comment: @giser_yugang, yes, I am using it. But it is only fine for one csr_matrix. The headache is that I have 50 csr_matrix.